# map an array from an array of objects key/value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to take an array objects that and map it so that the new array is just a simple array if each object's id.

So for example:

```
[
    {id: 49, name: "Rest update test"},
    {id: 12, name: "Rest test"}
]
```

would become:

```
[49, 12]
```

i have tried this so far:

```
myObject.map(object => object.id);
```

so my actual function that is not working is the following, when I view the console.log, it is showing the original object:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd.map(object => object.id);
    console.log(this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd);
}
```

Comment: what does not work with that approach?

Comment: Could it be that you're missing a comma in your array definition? That map statement works fine as long as the map function is supported. In older browsers you need to use a `for` loop

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first object.

Comment: not the comma, sorry that is just a copy and past out of the `console.log` I forgot the comma in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the given code does not work, then you need to assign the result of mapping.

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not mutate the original array but return a new one.

```js
var array = [{ id: 49, name: "Rest update test" }, { id: 12, name: "Rest test" }],
    ids = array.map(object => object.id);

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: I added the function I am calling this in, as you can see. so do i need to reassign `this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd` to a variable within the function scope first?

Comment: `map` returns a new array and you need to assign it somwhere.